# DC-DC Converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter

There is confusion because the name of the dc-dc converter is, that it is isolated, but in the description, it says it does not provide isolate effect. Can you tell me what type dc-dc converter is **https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/New-Isolated-Power-Board-DC-DC-Converter-Input-Voltage-9V-36V-Output-12V-5W-/332099424095**?

https://p.globalsources.com/IMAGES/PDT/SPEC/009/K1160348009.pdf

Comment: It is something you're buying off of eBay, and therefor not to be trusted.

Comment: I understand what you say, but I would be very pleased if I know exactly what kind of dc-dc converter is.

Comment: You are asking a shopping question, which is not in the scope of this site.  If you have a data sheet for the thing and are having trouble interpreting it, post a link to the data sheet.

Comment: This is the datasheet: https://p.globalsources.com/IMAGES/PDT/SPEC/009/K1160348009.pdf

Comment: only the seller knows what `isolate effect` means because it is a translation .... it may not have anything to do with input/output isolation

Comment: Who gives a rat on what ebay seller writes, it could be "Size XXL". "Color: GREEN", and "easy to clean up"... It looks like a standard 5-W isolated converter to me, there are plenty of other reputable sources for these, and cheaper.

Comment: Please post this question to the eBay seller.  EE.SE isn't his volunteer technical support.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With a 2:1 V input range above and below the output of 12V, this is called an isolated "Buck-Boost or Flyback converter"

More research material  [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_converter)   and [there](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~ecen4517/materials/flyback.pdf)

**The flyback converter is based on the buck-boost converter.**

Such as TI's LM5160 for example, but there is no disclosure in your datasheet.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91962/discussion-on-answer-by-sunnyskyguy-ee75-dc-dc-converter).

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean. I just saw to many comments and moved them to chat. Didn't vote